# Positioning CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working in a project and I need some help. The following picture is the layout I need to create: [Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8W6I.png).

This picture, is the layout I'm getting: [Wrong layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IDuX.png)

The steps (welcome, preparation) should be one under the other, just like the
[RightLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8W6I.png).

So, here's my Main.js code that calls the NewAccordion function:

```
          if (procedures[step]){
            return (
              <NewAccordion
                key={`${index}-${step}`}
                index={index}
                opened={currentStepIndex === index}
                procedure={procedures[step]}
                commandSender={sendViewerMessage}
              />
            );
          } else return "";
        })}
```

The following code is the part of my NewAccording function that is wrong:

```
      <article className="angel__flow">
        <a
          data-toggle="collapse"
          onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
          className={`angel__flow__button ${show ? "active" : ""}`}
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseThree"
        >     
          {t(procedure.title[i18n.language])}
          <span class="angel__flow__button__number">{index+1}</span>  
        </a>
      </article>
```

The next code is the classname in css:

```
.angel__flow {
    display: block;
    width: 33.333333333333%;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So, guys, I really don't know what's wrong. I would really appreciate if any of you could help me. I'm sorry for my bad english, I'm from Brazil.

Comment: Can you use display: flex; flex-direction: column;  at class:  .angel__flow ?

Comment: I tried this and it the error continues

Comment: That's what float does... floats block elements beside one another. You need to look at using a different way to achieve this layout - take a look at flex, grids or even nested blocks if you need to do this this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this:

```
  <div className="angel__flow" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column">
        <a
          data-toggle="collapse"
          onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
          className={`angel__flow__button ${show ? "active" : ""}`}
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseThree"
        >     
          <span>{t(procedure.title[i18n.language])}</span>
          <span class="angel__flow__button__number">{index+1}</span>  
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you use div instead of article tag like the update one?